# How to implement dropWhile recursively using foldRight in Kotlin

Tags: recursion, collections, kotlin, higher-order-functions, fold

I've been implementing higher order functions recursively with `.foldRight()` like `any`, `all`, and `takeWhile` as practice, but `dropWhile` has been elusive. `_Collections.kt` has the imperative way but I couldn't convert it to a recursive structure.

For reference, this is `takeWhile`

```
fun takeWhile(list:List<Int>, func:(Int) -> Boolean):List<Int> = list.foldRight(emptyList(),
    { next:Int, acc:List<Int> -> if (func(next)) acc.plus(next) else emptyList() })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's outline the idea of the solution.

With `foldRight`, you can only process the items one by one from right to left, maintaining an accumulator.

The problem is, for an item at position `i`, the `dropWhile` logic makes a decision whether to include the item into the result or not based on whether there is an item at position `j <= i` that does not satisfy the predicate (include if yes). This means you cannot simply maintain the result items: for some items you already processed, you don't know if they should actually be included.

Example:

<sub>(we're processing the items right-to-left, so the prefix is unknown to us)</sub>

```
... (some unknown items) ... ... ... ... a b c d <--- (right-to-left)
                   predicate satisfied:  T T F T
```

As we discover more items on the left, there are two possibilities:

- We found the beginning of the sequence, and there were no items that gave `F` on the predicate:

  ```
            (the sequence start) y z a b c d <--- (right-to-left)
           predicate satisfied:  T T T T F T
                                 -------
                                   drop
  ```

  In this case, the prefix `y z a b` should be dropped.
- We found an item that does not satisfy the predicate:

  ```
  ... (some unknown items)  ...  w z a b c d <--- (right-to-left)
           predicate satisfied:  F T T T F T
                                 -------
                                 include
  ```

  Only at this point we know for sure that we need to include the items `w z a b`, we could not do that earlier because there could be the beginning of the sequence instead of item `w`, and then we should have dropped `z a b`.

But note that in both cases we are certain that the items `c d` are to be included into the result: that's because they have `c` with `F` predicate in front of them.

---

Given this, it becomes clear that, when processing the items right-to-left, you can maintain a separate list of items that are not certain to be included into the result and are either to be dropped or to be included when a `false` predicate result is encountered, together with the item that gave such `false` result.

My implementation:

<sub>I used a pair of two lists for the accumulator, where the first list is for the items that are certain to be included, and the second one for those which are not.</sub>

```
fun <T> List<T>.myDropWhile(predicate: (T) -> Boolean) =
    foldRight(Pair(emptyList<T>(), emptyList<T>())) { item, (certain, uncertain) ->
        if (predicate(item))
            Pair(certain, uncertain + item) else
            Pair(certain + uncertain + item, emptyList())
    }.first.reversed()
```

Example:

```
val ints = listOf(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4)
println(ints.myDropWhile { it == 0 }) // [1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4]
```

See: [runnable demo of this code with more tests](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/gtshaf3i7p07p181cnq8bbd3kl/tsr0gga37729387m1u44v8vbk).

---

**Note:** copying a read-only list by doing `uncertain + item` or `certain + uncertain + item` in each iteration gives `O(n^2)` worst-case time complexity, which is impractical. Using mutable data structures gives `O(n)` time.